# can we have methods as arguments in a class definition?

Tags: scala

Following is the snippet of code I was going thru a scala book.
One of the parameter of the Car class is "def color: String"

I didn't understand. "def" is a keyword to define a method. how can that be used in paramenters?

```
scala> abstract class Car {
 |   val year: Int
 |   val automatic: Boolean = true
 |   def color: String
 | }
```

Comment: why is "def" being used. parameters should be nothing or val or var. what is "def"  doing in parameters

Comment: I don't see any parameters anywhere, nor do I see arguments. Can you clarify your question, please?

Comment: Oh, I think @Jason is mixing up class parameters with class members!

Comment: sorry. I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function that takes other functions are arguments is known as a **higher-order function**, here is an example of that:

```
// A function that takes a list of Ints, and a function that takes an Int and returns a boolean.
def filterList(list: List[Int], filter: (Int) => Boolean) = { /* implementation */ }

// You might call it like this
def filter(i: Int) = i > 0
val list = List(-5, 0, 5, 10)
filterList(list, filter)

// Or shorthand like this
val list = List(-5, 0, 5, 10)
filterList(list, _ > 0)
```

However that is not what is happening in your example.  In your example the `Car` class has three class members, two of them are variables, and one of them is a function.  If you were to extend your abstract class, you could test the values out:

```
abstract class Car {
  val year: Int
  val automatic: Boolean = true
  def color: String
}

case class Sedan(year: Int) extends Car {
  def color = "red"
}

val volkswagen = Sedan(2012)
volkswagen.year       // 2012
volkswagen.automatic  // true
volkswagen.color      // red
```

Here, having color as a function (using `def`) doesn't make too much sense, because with my implementation, the color is always going to be `"red"`.

A better example for using a function for a class member would be for some value that is going to change:

```
class BrokenClock {
  val currentTime = DateTime.now()
}

class Clock {
  def currentTime = DateTime.now()
}

// This would always print the same time, because it is a value that was computed once when you create a new instance of BrokenClock
val brokenClock = BrokenClock()
brokenClock.currentTime // 2017-03-31 22:51:00
brokenClock.currentTime // 2017-03-31 22:51:00
brokenClock.currentTime // 2017-03-31 22:51:00

// This will be a different value every time, because each time we are calling a function that is computing a new value for us
val clock = Clock()
clock.currentTime // 2017-03-31 22:51:00
clock.currentTime // 2017-03-31 22:52:00
clock.currentTime // 2017-03-31 22:53:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler for explaining in great detail. Very kind of you